# Are there any resources to learn German using the 10000-sentence method?

Tags: learning, standard-german

Learning languages using sentences is kind of similar the way children learn to speak, IMHO! First, you learn and memorize the common sentences and then use these to interact in everyday situations. This gives you confidence and also helps to expand your vocabulary. You also understand the sentence construction. Eventually, you also learn to modify the sentence structure/vocabulary and become a more fluent user.

I was wondering if there are any resources that provide carefully chosen German sentences for this purpose. Tia!

[10000 Sentences: Learn Any Language](http://learnanylanguage.wikia.com/wiki/10000_Sentences)

Comment: Link only questions look like spam and are likely to get deleted. Also it's unclear what you are asking without following the link. Please elaborate what your question is.

Comment: I think it is unusable. To learn a language, you have to learn the grammatik, and you have to learn around 2000 words. In the case of English, you also have to learn to speak and to hear again. German is much better, although the actually spoken language has a strong English flavor in this sense, which is not teached in a language school. You need also a private teacher. If you go into any new environment, you will have to learn around 500 words what you missed earlier, so it doesn't matter how good are you in German, your first time in native environment will be hard.

Comment: Even toddlers don't learn the language on this way. First they use only single words, and from your sentences they "hear" only the words what they already know and ignore the others.

Comment: @peterh To answer this question, it’s not important whether the assumption about learning is true.
If asking for a resource to learn German according to a certain method is a valid question in our SE, then this question is valid, too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/), a general memorizing app, and in its [ressources for German](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/german), there's also a [10000 sentences deck](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/601544200).

Comment: Interesting! - And can you recommend it? Any comment? - First thing I saw was a sample sentence *Ich kann meine Zehen nicht fühlen*, the usefulness of which is a bit foggy for me... but well, perhaps as one of 10 000 sentences...

Comment: Though the audio is computer-generated, both the German and English are well pronounced. The collection of sentences seem okay, and *Ich kann meine Zehen nicht fühlen* is clearly useful should you ever had an accident.

Comment: @Janka Yes, I see the medical use-case of *Ich kann meine Zehen nicht fühlen*. On the other hand, the criterion for selecting sentences in this sample should not be the principal usefulness in order to ensure survival, rather the probability that a sentence will occur in everyday life situations. In about four dozen years of life I never was in a situation where I would have used that sentence in any language. - But that's of course now a rather marginal consideration, as the interesting topic was here that there is at all such a collection of sentences. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 5):

**First a note of scepticims** (but not regarding the method, rather regarding the question):

I really sympathize with the method and believe that it can be powerful. However, I think your question itself contradicts the method. Here is a (crucial) quote from the first paragraphs of the description you linked:

"*The sentences should also reflect your personal daily life to make them more meaningful to you: i.e., things you yourself want/need to be able to say.*"

So, asking for a ready-made list of sentences is counter-intuitive. I suppose the idea would be that youself choose those sentences, e.g. by asking friends. (That's how I learnt Bulgarian, chiefly!)

**Now anyway an answer**

What I found extremely useful for learning foreign languages was reading 
Mickey Mouse comics in the given language (Russian, Serbian, Turkish, Bulgarian, French, whatever).

The reason is: Mickey Mouse has everyday language in an everyday scenery, and the style of speaking is both natural and refined, so to say a tasteful and grammatically flawless way of speaking casually. This may vary depending on the translation, but for German, reading **Micky Maus** comics is definitely a good idea. The German Micky Maus translations by [Erika Fuchs](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erika_Fuchs) (1906-2005) are even famous for their exquisite (but unobtruvise) style and they are said to have been formative for German spoken language after WWII in various ways.

You can read (preferably older) Micky Maus and Donald Duck stories and pick the sentences you like and that you think are likely to be useful in your own everyday life.

Comment: Your recommendation might end up in a pretty squeaky pronounciation.

Comment: @tofro Lach! Grunz! Kicher!

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann thanks for sharing your valuable opinion!